# Blur part of background image in QML/Qt

Tags: qt, qml

I'm fairly new to QML/Qt. Basically I would like to know how to apply a blur to the *inside* of the white rectangle seen on the photo below and only the inside so that it blurs the part of the background image within the rectangle. I tried doing this in a normal Qt project but don't think its possible without using QML.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. Use `ShaderEffectSource` item:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import "qrc:/"

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Image {
        id: bug
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: 32
        height: 32
        source: "qrc:/Original_bug.png"
        ShaderEffectSource{
            id: shader
            sourceItem: bug
            width: 128
            height: 128
            anchors{
                right: parent.right
                rightMargin: 32
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            sourceRect: Qt.rect(x,y, width, height)
        }
        GaussianBlur {
            anchors.fill: shader
            source: shader
            radius: 8
            samples: 4
        }
    }
}
```

Using `sourceRect` property you can specify an area to be blurred.

[image]

There are some issues when resizing the source image. This example works good only for static one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Do think there is anyway to achieve the same effect in qt without using QML. Just standard qt widgets and graphics effects?

Comment: @aman blurring an image itself is possible in Qt. You can check this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-effects-blurpicker-example.html . Yet, I'm not sure how to achieve exact behavior which you need